# Inserting a comma in between letter and number

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I am a beginner to programming and had a quick question about regex matching and wanted to know if a quick solution existed in bash or perl to the following problem:

My file looks something like this.

```
Boy0.545, 35, 63, 75  
Girl, 63, 723, 845, 45  
Human13, 453, 634, 43
```

How would I insert a comma whenever a letter was followed DIRECTLY after by a number in each line? I was reading up on some regex and felt like something like this could work: /^[:alpha:][:digit:]$/ but am unsure how to continue. I would like to have

```
Boy, 0.545, 35, 63, 75  
Girl, 63, 723, 845, 45  
Human, 13, 453, 634, 43
```

Any help is appreciated. Apologies for the simple question! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat testfile
Boy0.545, 35, 63, 75
Girl, 63, 723, 845, 45
Human13, 453, 634, 43

$ sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\([0-9]\)/\1, \2/g' testfile
Boy, 0.545, 35, 63, 75
Girl, 63, 723, 845, 45
Human, 13, 453, 634, 43
```

`\([A-Za-z]\)` and `\([0-9]\)` are *capturing groups*, which are referred to in the replacement section by `\1` and `\2`, respectively. So we look for a number immediately following a letter, and replace it with the letter, then a comma, then a space, then the number.

You can also use *POSIX character classes* as you mentioned in your post:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\1, \2/g' testfile
```

Comment: Thank you.Very informative answer -- thanks for your help! Definitely learned a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use capture groups to copy the letter and number into the replacement.

```
perl -pe 's/([a-z])(\d)/$1, $2/i'
```

`$1` and `$2` are replaced with the parts of the original string that matched the patterns enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: This fails with BSD `sed`. It doesn't like `/i`.

Comment: @John1024 In fairness to Will, `bash` usually implies using tools like `sed`, `awk`, `tr`, etc.

Comment: I made it clear that this was for perl and upvoted it.